# Power Bi - line chart - add two lines trend to issue and receipt

Tags: powerbi, visualization, linechart

In Power BI, there is a LINE CHART that shows weekly purchases and production consumption.

**1. How can I display two trend lines, one for purchases and another for consumption?
2. Also, how can I make it show the month without breaking it down into individual weeks?**

[PRINT SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUgs2.png)

I tried to create a chart in Power BI that displays both weekly purchases and production consumption. I managed to create the chart but wasn't sure how to add two separate trend lines—one for purchases and another for consumption. Additionally, I wanted to figure out how to display the data on a monthly basis without it being broken down into individual weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a date dimension/calendar table in your model? If you have {date, month number, month name, week number, etc} you just put the Month Name or Month Year on the X-axis. (I'd use Month Year = DATE(DimDate[Year],DimDate[Month No],1) to do this because it'll sort properly.